# 8 people are seated in a row. What is the probability 2 people are at least 2 seats apart?

Tags: probability

My attempt: there are 5 ways they can have 2 seats between them, 4 ways they can have 3 seats between them, and so on, so that I got 5+4+3+2+1=15. multiply that by 2 because there are two of them, and multiply that by 6! for the remaining 6 people, so I got $$\frac{(5+4+3+2+1)\cdot 2\cdot 6!}{8!}=0.536$$ Is this right?

Comment: I don´t think so. Try to calculate the converse probability. The probability, that 2 people are sitting next to each other.

Comment: @calculus: Or one seat apart.

Comment: @joriki Isn´t one seat apart the same like next to each other?

Comment: By "2 seats apart" do you mean that person $a$ and person $b$ have one seat with someone else between them ($axb$) or two seats with other people between them ($axxb$)?

Comment: @calculus: I don't understand. Of course one seat apart is the same as one seat apart. But it's not the same as next to each other (in the meaning of "one seat apart" that the OP is apparently using).

Comment: @joriki In german it is the same. I would be surprised, if it is different in english.

Comment: @calculus: German happens to be my other mother tongue :-) I'd say that in both German and English, it's ambiguous, and the meaning should be inferred from how the term is used in the question. It's clear from the question that "$2$ seats apart" and "$2$ seats between them" are being used synonymously.

Comment: @joriki I agree with your last sentence. But this was the interpretation of the OP. Anyway I apologize, that I misinterpretated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's right. It would have been slightly easier to calculate the probability of the complement: There are $6$ ways to have $1$ seat between them and $7$ ways to have no seats between them, leading to

$$
1-\frac{(6+7)\cdot2\cdot6!}{8!}\approx0.536\;.
$$